# Calibrating touch screen (multiple monitors)

Tags: 20.04, touchscreen, graphics-tablet, monitor-calibration

I have a drawing tablet that works fine when I'm mirroring all my monitors. Once I stop mirroring, the stylus touch is off by a couple inches, making it impossible to draw.

[with mirroring:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoXff.jpg)

[without mirroring the monitors:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrNkD.jpg)

When use the Calibrate Touchscreen application, nothing changes. It says to save the new calibration data into /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf. I did that, logged out and restarted. Nothing changes. Am I missing a step here? I'd love to utilize this $400 on Ubuntu, otherwise I'm going to have to partition a windows section on my hard drive -_-